# Poly() function in R for linear models

Tags: r, regression, polynomial

I am working with some data on which I used the `poly()` function to get 4th degree polynomials. I had one model that only had significance for the first degree, so I tried to simplify it and get different coefficients and other info under "Coefficients:" from the `summary()` function, by using `lm1=lm(data1~data2)` versus `lm2=lm(data1~poly(data2, degree=1))`.

My biggest question is should I use the `lm2` instead of the `lm1` in order to stay consistent with other models with higher degree polynomials?

Comment: Are you aware that `poly(data2, degree=1)` is simply a version of `data2` that has been centered to 0 and standardized to a Euclidean length of 1?

Comment: I was not aware of the standardization, thank you, that helps tremendously.

Comment: For the details of this, see the section headed "Orthogonal polynomials in one variable" in my post at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/408855/919.  The degree-one term is obtained by first "regressing against (a constant)," which centers it (takes out it mean) and then normalizing it.