# What are 'Polynomial feature expansions'?

Tags: regression, terminology, polynomial

I have a question where I am explaining what polynomial regression is and have been asked to make sure I cover certain points, one of which is 'Polynomial feature expansions' what exactly does this mean? I cant find anything online. Does it simply mean adding higher power X's to the linear regression model?

Comment: That is how I would interpret it

Comment: Something like this? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2205309/polynomial-regression-polynomial-expansion

Comment: Welcome to the site. One of the points you may be expected to cover is that base expansion is not simply squaring or cubing the original variable, but adding all polynomial terms up the desired power. Adding e.g. $x^2$, but not $x^1$ is [usually wrong](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/28741/176202).

Comment: One form of such "feature expansions" uses *orthogonal polynomials.*  I provide definitions, examples, and some discussion at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/253123.