# Effect of basis functions on the dimension of a linear regression model

Tags: regression, basis-function

In `Scikit-learn` I can use polynomial features to create polynomial linear regression models. `Scikit-learn` transforms my original data as follows. If I had a datapoint `[2]`, it would return `[2,4,8]` with 3 basis functions $(x, x^2, x^3).$ This means that it is increasing the dimensionality of the model, indeed because these monomials form a basis for the vector space of cubics. So the resulting model is a linear combination of monomials.

My question therefore is how do basis functions relate to the dimensionality of the model? Precisely which vector space do they form a basis for? How do we construct the linear regression model taking into account that vector space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The model space

As always in a linear model, with a $n\times k$ model matrix $X$ for $n$ observations and $k$ features, the space is the set of all possible vectors $X\beta$ where $\beta$ is the collection of $k$ coefficients (the "parameters").

Geometrically, the parameter $\beta\in\mathbb{R}^k$ is a vector and $X$ represents a linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^k$ to $\mathbb{R}^n.$  The model space is the image of $X.$  It's a linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n,$ the so-called "column space" of $X.$  Linear algebra tells us the dimension of this space equals the dimension of the domain $(k)$ *minus* the dimension of the kernel (the "null space" of $X$), whence the dimension cannot exceed $k$ and equals $k$ precisely when the only vector $\beta$ for which $X\beta=0$ is the zero vector itself.

#### The dimension of the space

**Can more be said?**  Yes, but it's a little delicate. Let's focus on the columns generated by monomials.  Suppose they correspond to $x^{e_1}, x^{e_2},$ and so on, through $x^{e_p},$ where all the exponents $e_j$ are distinct positive integers.  We may order the exponents so that $1\le e_1 \lt e_2 \lt \cdots \lt e_p,$ whence $e_p \ge p.$

Notice that when a value of $x$ is the same for two observations, these monomials generate identical rows, which therefore are linearly dependent: the extra rows do not change the dimension of the space of the model.  Thus, we only need to consider the *distinct* values of $x$ in the dataset.  Let there be $m\le n$ of these and let $X_0$ designate the model matrix for the $m$ distinct observations.

(Geometrically, the equality of some of the original values $x$ means the data reside in some $m$-dimensional subspace $V^m$ of $\mathbb{R}^n.$  Limiting to a set of unique rows of $X$ induces a linear isomorphism $\iota: V^m\to\mathbb{R}^m.$  $X_0$ thereby represents a linear transformation $X_0:\mathbb{R}^p \to \mathbb{R}^m$ given by applying $X$ and following that by $\iota.$  You did ask "precisely what vector space" was involved!)

**To compute the dimension of the model space,** let's do it indirectly by finding some null vectors.  That is, we seek $p$-vectors $\beta$ for which $X_0\beta=0.$  Writing these distinct values of $x$ as $x_1,x_2, \ldots, x_m,$ we have

$$X_0 = \left(x_i^{e_j}\right) = \pmatrix{x_1^{e_1} & x_1^{e_2} & \cdots & x_1^{e_p}\\
x_2^{e_1} & x_2^{e_2} & \cdots & x_2^{e_p}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
x_m^{e_1} & x_m^{e_2} & \cdots & x_m^{e_p}}.$$

The equation $X_0\beta = 0$ represents the *system* of simultaneous equations

$$\beta_1 x_i^{e_1} + \beta_2 x_i^{e^2} + \cdots + \beta_p x_i^{e^p} = 0,$$

$i = 1, 2, \ldots, m.$  In other words,

> All the $x_i$ are roots of the polynomial $\beta_1 T^{e_1} + \beta_2 T^{e_2} + \cdots + \beta_p T^{e_p}.$

Because the $x_i$ are distinct, this polynomial has *at least* $m$ roots.  The Fundamental Theorem of Algebra, which asserts any polynomial of degree $p$ (with real or complex coefficients) has at most $p$ distinct roots (real or complex), implies $e_p \ge m.$  Consequently,

> The kernel of the model matrix is $\{0\}$ whenever $e_p\lt m:$ that is, whenever the maximum power of your monomials is less than the number of distinct values of $x,$ the dimension of the space generated by those monomials equals the number of monomials.  There is no redundancy.

**An important corollary** is that when the powers are $e_j = 1,2,\ldots, p,$ then so long as you use fewer monomials $(p)$ than distinct values of $x$ $(m),$ the dimension of the model space will equal the number of monomials.

**As a simple common example,** suppose $x$ is a binary indicator, thereby limited to two values, and that both values appear in the data.  This result shows that when you are including an intercept in the model (essentially $x^0=1$) along with $x$ itself, it's pointless to introduce any more monomials.

#### Constructing a model matrix

It's usually not a good idea to work with the matrices $X$ and $X_0$ whose columns are monomials, because they often create numerical instabilities.  Part of the problem is that high powers grow very quickly.  If you have, say, distinct values of $x$ from $1$ through $10$ and you choose to include a monomial of degree $e_j=16$ or higher, $1^{e_j}$ is indistinguishable from $0$ in comparison to $10^{e_j}$ when you are using double-precision floating point arithmetic, as illustrated in Python 3.0 here:

[image: Input and output of floating point calculations]

Standardizing the columns helps a little, but not much, because the monomials tend to be nearly collinear anyway.  See [Why are there large coefficents for higher-order polynomial](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/233414/) for some discussion.

**The standard solution is to compute *orthogonal polynomials.***  These are linear combinations of the monomials $T^{e_j}$ that, *when applied to the values $x_i,$* give vectors that are orthogonal to each other.  (They form a different basis for the model space, but the model space is unchanged.)  The orthogonality is the opposite of nearly collinear: these new columns don't interfere with each other in the underlying calculations.  For much more about this, including some statistical subtleties, please read [Raw or orthogonal polynomial regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/258307).

An often overlooked point is that despite being called "orthogonal polynomials," which sounds kind of universal, the orthogonal polynomials depend on the specific distinct values $x_i.$  Some of the links I provide (above and below) mention good ways to compute the orthogonal polynomials for a dataset.

We have many good discussions and examples of the use of orthogonal polynomials in regression models: please see the results of [this site search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=orthogonal%20polynomial%20is%3aanswer%20score%3a5) for some of the better answers.

Finally, if you would like to see explicit examples of model matrices involving orthogonal polynomials, I included some in a [post on multivariate orthogonal polynomials.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/408855/919)